# Nuclear chemistry home made

Tags: home-experiment, nuclear-chemistry

A boy in Memphis built 1 year ago a nuclear fusion reactor at his home . How did he achieve so high temperatures in order for the fusion to take place?The fusion that took place was 2 atoms of hydrogen-2 were fused into helium.What I know is that hydrogen-2 can only be made by fusion of 2 hydrogen-1 atoms and then the unstable radioactive diproton which is produced is converted into hydrogen-2 and 1 positron.Where did he find so much energy? And if we pressure a gas very hard,can  we fuse 2 hydrogen atoms into 1 diproton?

Comment: This needs a reliable source.

Comment: They say, they milk hens beyond the ocean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [this really happened](https://www.sciencealert.com/a-14-year-old-kid-claims-to-have-created-a-nuclear-reaction-in-his-playroom-lab), *probably* (it's not a peer-reviewed effort).

The reactor is a [Farnsworth fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor), a very low-density, low-rate inertial-confinement reactor. They're surprisingly easy to build and get working; many people have done so, and verified their function by measuring neutron output. An accelerating voltage of 10 or 20 kV produces particle energies equivalent to over 100 million degrees C.

There's active debate about whether a fusor of this design could ever produce more power than it consumes, but there's been some interest in using them as compact neutron sources (that you can actually switch on and off).

You asked about fusing hydrogen-1 to hydrogen-2. These experimenters don't attempt that; they just buy deuterium, which is also readily available.

Comment: A common pulsed neutron source is an very small LINAC (linear accelerator) which fires ionized deuterium (deuterons) at a target made of titanium which has tritium impregnated into it. In the target the D + T reaction occurs to form helium-4 and a neutron. Strictly speaking this is a fusion reaction, this is used in a range of applications including neutron activation analysis and the neutron source needed to power up a modern atomic (fission) bomb. While it is a fusion device it is never going to break even in terms of energy in / energy out